# Dynamic drop down list - want a way to store input in a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want an easy way to store the number selected from the drop down list in a variable.
How can I achieve this ? 
The drop down list is dynamic.

thanks

```
$results = $handle->query("SELECT * FROM id
 WHERE test  = '".$pull ."';");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='id'>";
   while($table = $results->fetchArray()){
      $tab= $tabe['ic'] -1;
      $b = "1" . $table_ ;
      echo '<option value="'.$tab.'">'.$tab.'</option>';
   }
echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selected value as following.

```
console.log($("select").val());
```

Comment: How does that work ? Like where do I put this in my current code. I am pretty new to all this.

Comment: @VHDLprog If you control this value, my answer is located in <script> tag, but if you don't control this and want to submit this data, my answer is not used, and you can move your select tag into form tag and submit that form.